# Android programmatically add fragment - position in parent and layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

OK, I'm trying to create a universal app that shows 3 tabs in phone view and 3 columns in tablet landscape. As such I created several different XML layouts using Linear Layout.

However, using fragments, I came across a problem - I want to remove the leftmost column when a selection is made in that fragment. I believed I could do this but it turns out I can't remove fragments declared in XML. So now, I'm tring to create the middle and right columns in XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/classification_fragment"
        android:name="uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.fragments.MenuClassificationFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/list_classifications" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then add the first column using

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        MenuCountryFragment countryFragment=new MenuCountryFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.menu_layout, countryFragment, "country_menu").commit();
```

but I have two problems:

a) The above code only puts the fragment at the right hand side of the Linear Layout and I can't specifiy position. It needs to be on the left.

b) XML gave me the freedom to define different weights for the fragment based on screen size/orientation. Setting layout parameters programmatically in the Fragments seems a backward step. I got round this by putting a placeholder view in the xml that I read the layout params from this and assign them in onCreateView but its a hack.

I know I can put the fragment in the correct place by adding it as a child of the first element in the xml but when I do this and remove the fragment it leaves a blank space.

Answer (score 2):

Create a placeholder for the new fragment you want to add (in your XML), something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/classification_fragment"
        android:name="uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.fragments.MenuClassificationFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/list_classifications" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, instead of adding a new fragment at runtime, replace the content of the empty container...

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MenuCountryFragment countryFragment=new MenuCountryFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFrag).commit();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had thought that replace only worked for fragments? - from  [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) - **replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container.**. Will test when I get home. Will this pick up the FrameLayout layout properties?

Comment: OK, reading the docs again what I'm expecting this to do is to remove existing Fragments from the FrameLayout (there are none) then to add the new Fragment as a child of that layout. However I don't see how this is better than just calling add(...) and it produces the same problem - when the Fragment is removed later the FrameLayout still exists with a weight and so takes up room on the screen but with no content. I want the remaining two fragments to take over all of the space.

Comment: Just to follow up I can confirm that this answer doesn't work, I ended up keeping my xml layout, using hide() instead of remove() and setting the layout to automatically animate changes in xml.